# HttpServletRequest getParameter unable to retrieve parameters with &amp;

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, httprequest

I have a url, something like this `localhost:8080/foo.action?param1=7&param2=8&param3=6`

When this is the Url (as it is), `request.getParmeter("param2")` gives me `8` [Correct]

i) When the encoding converts this url to `localhost:8080/foo.action?param1=7%26param2=8%26param3=6`

In this case, `request.getParameter("param1")` gives me `7&param2=8&param3=6`

ii) When the encoding converts this url to `localhost:8080/foo.action?param1=7&amp;param2=8&amp;param3=6`

In this case, `request.getParameter("param1")` gives me `7` and `request.getParameter("param2")` gives me null

What is the correct way of retrieving the parameters? [Assuming that using one of the two Url encoding schemes is unavoidable]

(I am using struts actions)

Comment: you should decode the URL
&amp; should be &

Comment: In my struts action, I say request.getParameter("paramName"). How do I explicitly decode the whole Url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `req.getQueryString()` to get the whole query parameters and then do server side decoding based on whatever encoding methods you choose.

Comment: Although I didn't want to do this, I couldn't find a better way. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please don't do this. Rather, don't encode the ampersands as they are supposed to be there specifically to allow proper parsing. See alexey28's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent this do not encode parameters with delimeters, encode only parameters values. This will be the best way. If you cannot handle parameters encoding just do decoding on server side before parsing:

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(queryString, "UTF-8");
String[] pares = decoded.split("&");
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(String pare : pares) {
    String[] nameAndValue = pare.split("=");
    parameters.put(nameAndValue[0], nameAndValue[1]);
}

// Now you can get your parameter:
String valueOfParam2 = parameters.get("param2");
```

Comment: You should call URLDecode.decode() when adding the keys and values to the Map. Otherwise you might run into problems if the query string contains encoded & characters (like %26). In this case the decoded.split() call will "generate" unwanted key/value pairs.

Comment: Yes. As @Marcel says, the code is not correct - do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
String[] Parameters = = URLDecoder.decode(Request.getQueryString(), 'UTF-8').splitat('&') ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code is not correct - when decoding the query string, you may get extra "&" chars (that were encoded in URL).

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me today. Turns out I was passing the encoded url over the wire.  When the request is made it should be made as `http://localhost/foo?bar=1&bat=2` not as `http://localhost/foo?bar=1&amp;bat=2`.

In this case I had cut the url from an xml file and pasted it into a browser.